# Small word document taking a long time to open in 2003

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003

I have a 300kb word file that is taking 15+ seconds to load in word 2003. It seems fine in 2007 and 2010. How can I identify which part of the file is causing the slow down.

*PS. i found an article on technet which hinted it may be trying to find templates, but it is not that.*

Comment: No macros in the file BTW

Comment: is the file you are trying to open located on your machine, or on another computer on the network?

Comment: its on a network drive. But its not slow or anything. It loads really quick in 2010

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any elements that link to external resources, such as `IncludePicture`, `IncludeText` etc?

You might just be lucky enough to narrow down what is causing the problem by removing parts of the document peice by peice, trying each time to open it until the document loads normally. If this does work then the content you just removed before it started working will give an indication of what's causing the problem.

Also note, it could just be something to with compatibility gone wrong and the document just needs a resave to work properly.